# Large cube root and fourth root in unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

XITS math font, for example, has the large `\cuberoot` etc (`uni221B.size1` etc). But different from `\sqrt`, the large variants will not be used automatically. So how can I use the large `\cuberoot` and `\fourthroot` in `unicode-math`?

### Update

Now `\cuberoot` and `\fourthroot` will load the large symbols automatically in `unicode-math` v0.8m (2018/07/29).

Comment: 2221B I assume you mean

Comment: It's actually `U+221B` and `U+221C`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unicode-math` is supposed to have an interface for declaring radicals but it didn't work as I expect.

However the xetex/luatex primitive works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}


\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

$\sqrt{x} \quad \sqrt{\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{C}}$


$\cuberoot{x} \quad \cuberoot{\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{C}}$

\def\cbr{\Uradical\symoperators "0221B\relax}
$\cbr{x} \quad \cbr{\frac{\frac{A}{B}}{C}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will opened an issue to improve the `unicode-math` interface here https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/476